# How to direct output of time command to a file in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, time, append

This does not append the output of the time command to `file.txt`

```
echo $(time openssl genrsa -aes128 -out server.key 1024) &> file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
 {time openssl genrsa -aes128 -out server.key 1024} 2>> file.txt
```